# Анимация вокруг своей оси

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация, css-animation

Кто имеет опыт создания анимаций по типу, как на главной странице сайта **[SimilarWeb](https://www.similarweb.com/)**?!
Задача в создании анимации, которая вращается по своей оси!

*Скрин:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Визуальное решение задачи увидите на [тестовой версии](http://workout.korets.in.ua/xbolt/index.html) сайта.
Спасибо **@Геннадий Журов** и **@Alexandr_TT**!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте свойство `transform-origin`. Координаты точки трансформации считаются от верхнего левого угла элемента. Вращаем вокруг центра солнца.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.solar-system{
  background-color:#002;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.sun{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:yellow;
  box-shadow:0 0 20px 2px yellow;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 25px);
  left:calc(50% - 25px);
}
.mercury-orbit{
  width:130px;
  height:130px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 65px);
  left:calc(50% - 65px);
}
.mercury{
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:gray;
  top:calc(50% - 5px);
  left:calc(50% - 70px);
  transform-origin:70px 5px;
  animation:4s mercury infinite linear;
}
@keyframes mercury{
  from{
    transform:rotate(0)
  }
  to{
    transform:rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="solar-system">
  <div class="sun"></div>
  <div class="mercury-orbit"></div>
  <div class="mercury"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Геннадий, спасибо за качественный ответ и ваши старания!!
Оказалось куда проще, чем думал))

Answer (score 6):

### svg + css

Спорить, что лучше `CSS` или `SVG` абсолютно не конструктивно.
 Это относится не к конкретному топику, а к тенденции запросов на выполнение той или иной задачи. 
Вроде этого,- "Cделайте мне только на CSS или только на SVG"

Нужно использовать и то и другое. Обе эти спецификации имеют достаточное проникновение друг в друга и прекрасно работают совместно.

Многих пугают очень длинные строки SVG формул, поэтому попытаюсь их сделать в стиле CSS.

Взял в качестве основы хороший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/917216/28748) @Геннадия Журова  и попытался сделать микс `CSS+SVG`

```css
.solar-system {
  background-color: #002;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.sun {
  fill: yellow;
  filter: url(#dropShadow);
}

.mercury-orbit {
  stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: none;
}

.mercury {
  fill: crimson;
  filter: url(#dropShadow2);
}
```

```html
<div class="solar-system">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 400"> 
  
  <defs>
    <filter 
      id="dropShadow" 
      x="-20%" y="-20%" 
      width="150%" height="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
    <filter 
      id="dropShadow2" 
      x="-20%" y="-20%" 
      width="120%" height="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <circle class="sun" cx="250" cy="175" r="25" /> 
  <g>
    <animateTransform 
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="rotate" 
      values="0 250 175;360 250 175" 
      dur="12s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <circle class="mercury-orbit" cx="250" cy="175" r="65" />
    <circle class="mercury" cx="185" cy="175" r="6" />
  </g>
  
</div>
```

Связанная тема: [Анимация планет солнечной системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918237/28748)

Comment: спасибо, вот результат работы на главной странице.  
_Тестовая версия сайта ->_ [XBOLT](http://workout.korets.in.ua/xbolt/index.html)