# Как создать анимированные звёзды в космосе?

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация

Делаю анимацию вращения планет солнечной системы.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918238/28748

Не хватает реалистичного, анимированного фона звездного неба, как на картинке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Величина звёзд их яркость, взаимное расположение должно быть случайным.

Желательно добавить мерцание более крупных звёзд.

С помощью svg я не могу сделать подобный эффект, так как в этом языке нет ничего подобного, как в `JS` `Math.random()`

Как реализовать подобную анимацию на `Javascript`?

Comment: в центре яркость больше это просто фон или как-то светимость должна складываться?

Comment: @Grundy Ну по идее там должен быть млечный путь, но можно обойтись и без него.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В качестве одного из вариантов, можно создать кучу элементов, которые будут звездами, поставить им случайную позицию и размер.

Для некоторых, например размер которых больше установленного значения, добавить класс css, добавляющий мерцание.

Например так:

```js
function createStar(center, radius, animation) {
  var star = document.createElement('div');
  star.className = 'star';
  star.style.width = `${radius}px`;
  star.style.height = `${radius}px`;
  star.style.top = `${center.top-radius/2}px`;
  star.style.left = `${center.left-radius/2}px`;
  star.style.animationDelay = `${animation.delay}s`;
  star.style.animationDuration = `${animation.duration}s`;
  if (radius > 6) {
    star.classList.add('shine');
  }
  return star;
}
var container = document.getElementById("d");
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  container.appendChild(createStar({
    top: getRandom(0, container.offsetHeight),
    left: getRandom(0, container.offsetWidth)
  }, getRandom(2, 7), {
    duration: getRandom(3, 15, false),
    delay: getRandom(0, 7, false)
  }));
}

function getRandom(min, max, notFloor) {
  return (!notFloor && Math.floor || (a => a))(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#d {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #040e17;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.star {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.shine {
  animation: shine infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shine {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Вместо обычных элементов, можно так же работать и с элементами svg с настроенной анимацией, возможно даже лучше будет.

Comment: `"Величина звёзд их яркость, взаимное расположение должно быть случайным."` а у вас кроме мерцания звёзд статика Я понял ваш совет, но через smil будет оч. убого и тормозно

Comment: Расположение случайно :-) несколько раз нажмешь выполнить - будут разный размер в разных местах

Comment: я был неправ динамика есть, но реалистичность хромает Уже увидел, до коментария :)))

Comment: Здесь надо экспериментировать с длительностью анимации и стилями для звезды вроде на сколько широко надо сияние делать и т.д.

Comment: а я и писал в вопросе `Со сроками не тороплю, интересует качество решения`  .

Comment: Здесь все упирается в то, что ты считаешь реалистичным, поэтому просто сам можешь поменять значения в строках с box-shadow и background-color.

Comment: Про smile имелось ввиду. что анимацию ты задаешь с помощью svg, а расположение с помощью js, примерно как тут

Comment: благодарю за советы и главное код. А то сделай второй вариант в отдельном ответе, я сравнивая варианты поучусь заодно JS/ Стили и анимашку я конечно смогу в svg сделать, но меня интересует более реалистична картина расположения звезд как на картинке в вопросе. А за эту часть должен отвечать JS/

Comment: так как расположение случайное - то возможно в одной из генераций они будут выглядеть лучше. можно попробовать так же поменять количество звезд

Comment: спасибо за оперативность, не ожидал так быстрого ответа, завтра, на свежую голову подумаю, как да что.

Comment: @ Grundy огромное спасибо Надеюсь, что дальше пойму, как заточить под себя :)

Comment: @Grundy, привет. Прикольный ответ. У меня вопрос.  Ты зря писать не будешь. так что будь другом объясни... Какой смысл у строки `return star;`  в функции `function createStar(center...`

Comment: @Air, как ни странно точно такой же какой и у любого другого return - что-то вернуть, в данном случае созданный элемент. Потом он сразу же добавляется в container: `.appendChild(createStar(...))`

Comment: @Grundy, все, сообразил... Благодарю...

Answer (score 15):

Приблизил к оригиналу насколько смог. Собственно, что делают звезды на небе? Ну, максимум, пульсируют или исчезают на время. Применив одну и ту же анимацию с разной длительностью получаем довольно реалистичный эффект. Размер звезд от одного до пяти пикселей, но с вероятностью в десять процентов мы генерируем звезду размеров `giant` - их в десять раз меньше и они немного больше остальных. В `#root>div` можно раскоментировать `blur` для большей реалистичности, но все будет лагать. Желательно развернуть на всю страницу.

```js
const params = {
  amount: 200,
  size: {
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    giant: 9
  },
  duration: {
    min: 5,
    max: 25,
  }
}
const randomBetween = (a, b) => {
  return (a + (Math.random() * (b - a)));
}

for (let i = 0; i < params.amount; i++) {
  let star = $("<div></div>");
  let size = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) === 0 ? params.size.giant : randomBetween(params.size.min, params.size.max);
  star.css({
    "width": size + "px",
    "height": size + "px",
    "left": randomBetween(0, 100) + "%",
    "top": randomBetween(0, 100) + "%",
    "box-shadow": "0 0 " + size + "px " + size / 2 + "px #043668",
    "animation-duration": randomBetween(params.duration.min, params.duration.max) + "s"
  });

  $("#root").append(star);
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(8, 25, 42, 1) 19%, rgba(1, 4, 6, 1) 100%);
}

#root {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#root>div {
  position: absolute;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(177, 198, 219, 1) 2%, rgba(5, 63, 118, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* filter:blur(1px); */
  animation: shine infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(.9);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .9;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(.2);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(.2);
    opacity: .1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(.5);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.9);
    opacity: .9;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Михаил, мне понравилось. По моему, непросвещенному мнению, ты действительно отлично сработал

Comment: галку переназначать не буду, по себя знаю, как это неприятно, когда сначала отдадут галочку, а потом заберут :)) Но я найду другие способы тебя отблагодарить. Надеюсь, что и другие люди положительно оценят   твой и `@Grundy`  ответы. Они того стоят!

Comment: Да не, я не претендую. Спасибо за интересные вопросы :)

Comment: Misha Saidov, @Alexandr_TT, у нас любитель интересных вопросов... Держи плюс

Answer (score 6):

Мои 5 копеек на WebGL =)

Чтобы использовать это в реальной жизни, нужно как минимум еще математический шум заменить на текстуру.

---

Seed для шума можно поменять вот в этой строчке

```
 #define r(x)     fract(1e4*sin((x) * 541.121))
```

и расположение звезд изменится

```html
<style>body{ margin:0;background-color:black;overflow:hidden}</style>
<canvas></canvas>
<script>
let fragCode = `
  precision highp float;

  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 res;

  // вращающийся гексагон 
  // https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4scXWS
  float star( vec2 uv ) { 
     vec2 r = sin(vec2(0, 1.57) + time);
     uv = abs( uv * mat2(r, -r.y, r.x) ) * mat2(2, 0, 1, 1.57); 
     return .1 / max(uv.x, uv.y);
  }

  // простенькие 1D 2D и 3D шумы
  #define r(x)     fract(1e4*sin((x) * 541.121))  
  #define sr2(x)   ( r(vec2(x,x+.1)) *2.-1. )
  #define sr3(x)   ( r(vec4(x,x+.1,x+.2,0)) *2.-1. )

  void main(void) {
    // текстурные координаты (от 0 до 1) и инверсия по y
    vec2 uv = 2. * gl_FragCoord.xy/res.x - 1.; 
    
  for (float i = 0.; i < 131.; i++) {
        gl_FragColor += 
            star (uv - sr2(i)*res/res.xy )  // звезда в случайном месте
            * r(i+.2)                       // случайный масштаб    
            * (1.+sin(time+r(i+.3)*5.))*.1  // масштаб от времени   
            * (1.+.1*sr3(i+.4));            // случайный цвет
    }

    gl_FragColor -= 1.;  // иначе ярко слишком =)
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.; // все не прозрачное
  }
`;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 coords;
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(fragCode, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

var time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
var res = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'res');

window.addEventListener('resize', resize, resize());
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(dt) {    
    gl.uniform1f(time,dt/1000);
    gl.uniform2f(res, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
}

function resize() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}


</script>
```

---

Вариант попроще, тут меньше итераций цикла в шейдере, меньше звезд и тормозов.

```html
<style>body{ margin:0;background-color:black;overflow:hidden}</style>
<canvas></canvas>
<script>
let fragCode = `
  precision highp float;

  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 res;

  // вращающийся гексагон 
  // https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4scXWS
  float star( vec2 uv ) { 
     vec2 r = sin(vec2(0, 1.57) + time);
     uv = abs( uv * mat2(r, -r.y, r.x) ) * mat2(2, 0, 1, 1.57); 
     return .2 / max(uv.x, uv.y);
  }

  // простенькие 1D 2D и 3D шумы
  #define r(x)     fract(1e4*sin((x) * 541.121))  
  #define sr2(x)   ( r(vec2(x,x+.1)) *2.-1. )
  #define sr3(x)   ( r(vec4(x,x+.1,x+.2,0)) *2.-1. )

  void main(void) {
    // текстурные координаты (от 0 до 1) и инверсия по y
    vec2 uv = 2. * gl_FragCoord.xy/res.x - 1.; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) {
        float s = float(i);
        gl_FragColor += 
            star(uv - sr2(s))                     // звезда в случайном месте
            * (2.0 + sin(time + r(s + 0.2)))*.04  // масштаб от времени   
            * (1.0 + 0.1*sr3(s + 0.1));           // случайный цвет
    }

    gl_FragColor -= 1.;  // иначе ярко слишком =)
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.; // все не прозрачное
  }
`;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 coords;
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(fragCode, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

var time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
var res = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'res');

window.addEventListener('resize', resize, resize());
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(dt) {    
    gl.uniform1f(time,dt/1000);
    gl.uniform2f(res, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
}

function resize() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}


</script>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92211/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q------).