# Как создать 3D сферу в CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, анимация, css-animation

Я пытался создать 3D сферу, используя только чистый CSS, но я не смог сгенерировать требуемую форму. Я видел     [`цилиндр`](http://jsfiddle.net/bmouxLwu/9/)     , но я не могу найти ссылку на создание реальной сферы.

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sphere {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 500%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5%;
}
.sphere::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  content: '';
  height: 45%;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sphere red"></div>
<div class="sphere green"></div>
<div class="sphere blue"></div>
<div class="sphere yellow"></div>
<div class="sphere"></div>
```

тем не мение:

- A: это просто 2D круги, а не 3D фигуры
- B: Я не могу повернуть их в 3d (я хочу иметь вращающееся
  изображение), подобное изображению шара.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/30891893/7394871

Comment: Оба ответа чудовищно тормозят на телефоне :( Для сфер есть WebGL)

Comment: @andreymal а никто и не обещал, что легко будет на телефоне :)

Comment: Конечно же имеется в виду именно html+css? Без svg тегов?)

Comment: Надеюсь, что появятся новые ответы, может быть от тех же авторов. Так как в старых ответах есть проблемы. Читайте комментарии под старыми ответами.

Comment: И ещё, что по вашему сфера? Это в любом случае проекция на экран, т.е. эллипс в общем случае, скажем так: какими свойствами должно обладать это изображение, чтобы это считать сферой

Comment: @Stranger in the Q конкурс открыл не я и решение соответственно будет принимать автор конкурса, поэтому вопросы наверное нужно адресовать не мне :)

Comment: Кхм, простите не посмотрел)), однако Вы автор вопроса, хоть он и переводной, и было бы неплохо узнать Ваше мнение на этот счёт, и может быть добавить критерии в вопрос :)

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q кто платит, тот и заказывает музыку :)) Не могу я вносить дополнительные критерии.

Comment: @Air Ну нет слов (((( Зачем закрывать конкурс раньше на 6 дней? Люди, понимаешь приготовились давать новые ответы, может быть и  `@Misha Saidov` как-то улучшил бы свой ответ. А теперь естественно ни у кого нет никаких стимулов.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Мне очень понравился ответ Миши Саидова

Comment: @Air Ну так и закрывал бы через 30 секунд после открытия, а не через сутки.  Или через 7 дней, как положено. А тут не то, не сё

Comment: @Alexandr_TT. все я верно сделал.... Но почему-то мне система не дала сразу наградить человека, а только через  сутки...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Я пытался.

Не совсем понял о каких неокрашенных сегментах шла речь. Сама карта, которая накладывалась в том примере имела альфа-канал по бокам. Очень сложно (настолько, что можно сказать, невозможно) будет написать алгоритм накладывания овальной карты, но это все я заметил слишком поздно и к этому моменту уже написал бОльшую часть кода сферы.

Не сказать, что получилось чем-то лучше, но хоть геометрию вспомнил :) Код полностью мой, к @ZulNs не подглядывал, если необходимо - дам комментарий по любой интересующей строке. Для веселья добавил выбор карт :) Собственно вот:

```js
class Sphere {
  constructor(props) {
    props = (props.constructor.name === "Object" ? props : {});
    this.element = (props.element instanceof HTMLElement ? props.element : document.body);
    this.radius = (typeof props.radius === "number" ? props.radius : 100);
    this.polygonsPerMeridian = (typeof props.polygonsPerMeridian === "number" ? props.polygonsPerMeridian : 15);
    this.texture = (typeof props.texture === "string" ? props.texture : "none");
    this.rotate = (typeof props.rotate === "boolean" ? props.rotate : true);
    this.rotationTime = (typeof props.rotationTime === "number" ? props.rotationTime : 10);
    this.diameter = this.radius * 2;
    this.polygonSize = Math.ceil(this.radius * (2 * Math.tan(Math.PI / ((this.polygonsPerMeridian - 1) * 2))));
    this.parts = {
      sphere: null,
      meridians: [],
      polygons: []
    };
    this.handlers = {
      createSphereElement: () => {
        let sphere = document.createElement("div");
        sphere.classList.add("sphere");
        sphere.style.width = `${this.diameter}px`;
        sphere.style.height = `${this.diameter}px`;
        this.rotate && (sphere.style.animation = `rotate linear ${this.rotationTime}s infinite`);
        this.parts.sphere = sphere;
        return sphere;
      },
      createMeridianElement: () => {
        let meridian = document.createElement("div");
        meridian.classList.add("meridian");
        this.parts.meridians.push(meridian)
        return meridian;
      },
      createPolygonElement: (m, p) => {
        let x = this.radius * Math.cos((p * (Math.PI * 2)) / (this.polygonsPerMeridian - 1));
        let scaleXK = (1 - (.2 * (100 - (((this.radius - x) * 100) / (this.radius * 2))) / 100));

        let polygon = document.createElement("div");
        polygon.classList.add("polygon");
        polygon.style.backgroundImage = `url('${this.texture}')`;
        polygon.style.backgroundPosition = `${-m * this.polygonSize}px ${-(p * this.polygonSize)}px`;
        polygon.style.backgroundSize = `${((this.polygonsPerMeridian - 1) * 2) * this.polygonSize}px ${this.polygonsPerMeridian * this.polygonSize}px`;
        polygon.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${0}, ${0}, ${(p * 255) / this.polygonsPerMeridian})`;
        polygon.style.transformOrigin = `center center ${-this.radius}px`;
        polygon.style.width = `${this.polygonSize}px`;
        polygon.style.height = `${this.polygonSize}px`;
        polygon.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in-out";
        polygon.style.transform = `translateX(${((this.diameter / 2) - (this.polygonSize / 2))}px) translateY(${((this.diameter / 2) - (this.polygonSize / 2))}px) translateZ(${this.radius}px) rotateY(${(m * (180 * 2)) / ((this.polygonsPerMeridian - 1) * 2)}deg) rotateZ(${((p * 180) / (this.polygonsPerMeridian - 1)) - 90}deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) scaleX(${scaleXK})`;
        return polygon;
      },
      renderSphere: () => {
        let sphere = this.handlers.createSphereElement();
        for (let m = 0; m < ((this.polygonsPerMeridian - 1) * 2); m++) {
          let meridian = this.handlers.createMeridianElement();
          for (let p = 0; p < this.polygonsPerMeridian; p++) {
            let polygon = this.handlers.createPolygonElement(m, p);
            this.parts.polygons.push(polygon);
            meridian.appendChild(polygon);
            sphere.appendChild(meridian);
          }
        }
        this.element.appendChild(sphere);
      }
    }
    this.handlers.renderSphere();
  }

  setTexture(texture) {
    this.texture = (typeof texture === "string" ? texture : "none");
    this.parts.polygons.forEach(item => item.style.backgroundImage = `url('${texture}')`);
  }
}

new Sphere({
  element: document.body,
  radius: 150,
  polygonsPerMeridian: 13,
  texture: "https://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/743786736932356097/1240/10/scaletowidth",
  rotate: true,
  rotationTime: 10,
});

new Sphere({
  element: document.body,
  radius: 50,
  polygonsPerMeridian: 13,
  texture: "https://static-2.gumroad.com/res/gumroad/5387571460549/asset_previews/b455aaa72d1482e171f0558c2766cd48/retina/Mars_2k_Color_Preview_v001.jpg",
  rotate: true,
  rotationTime: 20,
});

new Sphere({
  element: document.body,
  radius: 30,
  polygonsPerMeridian: 13,
  texture: "https://static-2.gumroad.com/res/gumroad/5387571460549/asset_previews/d7c3b214de778aa83aa0a0ab32eec4c1/retina/Moon_2k_Preview.jpg",
  rotate: true,
  rotationTime: 5,
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sphere {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.meridian {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.polygon {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 360deg);
  }
}
```

На вход радиус, кол-во полигонов на один меридиан и картинка, желательно прямоугольная, без альфа-каналов. Если на вход будет квадратная картинка то она растянется до нужных размеров.

**Минусы:**

1. У полюсов, там, где искажение карты наиболее сильное, полигоны накладываются друг на друга ибо не имеют "меридианной" перспективы. В коде это частично решается при помощи сложно формулы расчета `scaleX` полигона ближе к полюсам (`scaleXK`), но и это не помогает в полной мере. Это самый основной минус, но думаю я продолжу работать над скриптом и поправлю это дело.
2. Иногда появляются щели между полигонами. Скорей всего это проблема позиционирования элементов браузером, т.к. формулы расчета размера полигонов правильные. Хотфикс: добавление нескольких пикселей к размеру полигона.

**Плюсы:**

1. Код довольно компактный, если опустить кучу строк, которые уходят на создание селекта и на хранение ссылок карт в параметрах.
2. Масштабируемость
3. Анимацией занимается графический ускоритель

В идеале можно превратить весь код в класс, чтобы можно было создавать кучу сфер с разными параметрами. Буду рад, если более опытные программисты тоже помогут в устранение минусов.

**UPD 10.02.2019:** Реализовал классы. Теперь удобно создавать новые сферы, можете оценить на примере 3-х планет с разными временем вращения, размером и детализацией.

**UPD 11.02.2019:** Добавил новы метод `setTexture(textureSrc)`. С его помощью можно плавно менять текстуру "на лету". [Оформил](https://github.com/mikhailsdv/JSSphere) небольшой репозиторий на GitHub.

Comment: Мне очень понравилось ваше решение, ваша дополнительная фича по подбору карт. Сейчас я дам ссылку на вашу работу в главный чат, процитирую ваши комментарии о минусах, которые вы видите в своем решении и приглашу знатоков JS поучаствовать в устранении их

Comment: В Firefox не работает

Comment: @andreymal пока не фокусировался на кроссбраузерности

Comment: @andreymal обновил код. Тепер в версии 64.0.2 тоже работает. На счет более ранних версий не знаю, но должно.

Comment: @Misha Saidov посмотрел доработанную версию. **Действительно сейчас работает в `FF`, `Opera`,  `Yandex`** .  Здорово! Понял, почему на чёрном фоне не стали делать, - сегменты и довольно крупные,  по окружности становятся ещё заметней. А уменьшение размеров сегментов, то есть увеличение их количества совсем убьет рендеринг? Будет периодически дёргаться?  Благодарю, что откликнулись на сложный вопрос, если что-то  попадётся в будущем интересненькое, обращаться к вам?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так уж получается, что нужно выбирать между детализацией и производительность. Можно еще пойти в оптимизацию и рендерить только ту часть сферы, которая видна сейчас. Так можно будет создавать сферы того же размера, но с удвоенной детализацией, но будет сложно синхронизировать css анимацию и этот механизм. Посмотрите в сторону `WebGL` и `three.js`. Думаю, в их арсенале найдется то, что вам нужно и с высокой производительностью. Из этого вопроса родилась полноценная библиотека для создания сфер, поэтому я всегда рад подобным вопросам, когда нужно немного поломать голову и погуглить)

Comment: @Misha Saidov Я знал, что вам интересно решать трудные задачки, Поэтому и обратился к вам. и рад, что получился положительный результат, который и вам  стал полезен. Если вы разрешите мне использовать свою библиотеку сфер, например в вопросе [анимации солнечной системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918237/28748), то я обязательно укажу ваше авторствоj Конечно я в курсе, что у `WebGL` не было бы проблем с производительностью.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Используйте конечно :)

Answer (score 7):

Чисто в CSS никак, но из той же серии, что Вы прислали с цилиндром как-то так ([источник](https://paulrhayes.com/creating-a-sphere-with-3d-css/)):

```js
$(function() {

  var el = document.createElement('div'),
    transformProps = 'transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform'.split(' '),
    transformProp = support(transformProps);

  function support(props) {
    for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (typeof el.style[props[i]] !== "undefined") {
        return props[i];
      }
    }
  }

  var $sphere = $('#sphere'),
    sphere = {
      rounds: 8,
      panels: 24,
      panelWidth: 100,
      el: $sphere.find('.container'),
      build: function(p, r) {

        var panels = p || this.panels,
          rounds = r || this.rounds,
          rotationPerPanel = 360 / panels,
          rotationPerRound = 360 / 2 / rounds,
          yRotation,
          xRotation,
          width = this.panelWidth,
          zTranslate = (width / 2) / Math.tan(rotationPerPanel * Math.PI / 180),
          $container = this.el,
          $ul,
          $li,
          i, j;

        this.el.html('');
        for (i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
          $ul = $('<ul>');
          xRotation = rotationPerRound * i;
          $ul[0].style[transformProp] = "rotateX(" + xRotation + "deg)";
          for (j = 0; j < panels; j++) {
            $li = $('<li>');
            yRotation = rotationPerPanel * j;
            $li[0].style[transformProp] = "rotateY(" + yRotation + "deg) translateZ(" + zTranslate + "px)";
            $ul.append($li);
          }
          $container.append($ul);
        }
      }
    },
    mouse = {
      start: {}
    },
    touch = document.ontouchmove !== undefined,
    viewport = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      el: $('#sphere .container')[0],
      move: function(coords) {
        if (coords) {
          if (typeof coords.x === "number") this.x = coords.x;
          if (typeof coords.y === "number") this.y = coords.y;
        }
        this.el.style[transformProp] = "rotateX(" + this.x + "deg) rotateY(" + this.y + "deg)";
      },
      reset: function() {
        this.move({
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        });
      }
    };

  sphere.build();

  $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 37: // left
        viewport.move({
          y: viewport.y - 90
        });
        break;

      case 38: // up
        evt.preventDefault();
        viewport.move({
          x: viewport.x + 90
        });
        break;

      case 39: // right
        viewport.move({
          y: viewport.y + 90
        });
        break;

      case 40: // down
        evt.preventDefault();
        viewport.move({
          x: viewport.x - 90
        });
        break;

      case 27: //esc
        viewport.reset();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    };
  }).bind('mousedown touchstart', function(evt) {
    delete mouse.last;

    evt.originalEvent.touches ? evt = evt.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
    mouse.start.x = evt.pageX;
    mouse.start.y = evt.pageY;
    $(document).bind('mousemove touchmove', function(event) {
      // Only perform rotation if one touch or mouse (e.g. still scale with pinch and zoom)
      if (!touch || !(event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get touch co-ords
        event.originalEvent.touches ? event = event.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
        $sphere.trigger('move-viewport', {
          x: event.pageX,
          y: event.pageY
        });
      }
    });

    $(document).bind('mouseup touchend', function() {
      $(document).unbind('mousemove touchmove');
    });
  });

  $sphere.bind('move-viewport', function(evt, movedMouse) {

    // Reduce movement on touch screens
    var movementScaleFactor = touch ? 4 : 1;

    if (!mouse.last) {
      mouse.last = mouse.start;
    } else {
      if (forward(mouse.start.x, mouse.last.x) != forward(mouse.last.x, movedMouse.x)) {
        mouse.start.x = mouse.last.x;
      }
      if (forward(mouse.start.y, mouse.last.y) != forward(mouse.last.y, movedMouse.y)) {
        mouse.start.y = mouse.last.y;
      }
    }

    viewport.move({
      x: viewport.x + parseInt((mouse.start.y - movedMouse.y) / movementScaleFactor),
      y: viewport.y - parseInt((mouse.start.x - movedMouse.x) / movementScaleFactor)
    });

    mouse.last.x = movedMouse.x;
    mouse.last.y = movedMouse.y;

    function forward(v1, v2) {
      return v1 >= v2;
    }
  });

  /* Change sphere style */
  $('#controls').bind('submit change', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $sphere.attr('class', '').addClass($(evt.target).val());
  });
});
```

```css
#sphere {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 200px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 200ms linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container>ul {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.container li {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.1;
  border-radius: 50px;
}


/* Different spheres */


/*************************************************/


/* Square */

#sphere.square li {
  border-radius: 0;
}


/* Kaleidoscope */

#sphere.kaleidoscope li {
  opacity: 0.9;
  -webkit-animation: borderRadius 5s linear infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: borderRadius 5s linear infinite alternate;
  animation: borderRadius 5s linear infinite alternate;
}


/* Eye */

#sphere.eye li {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sphere.eye li:nth-child(7),
#sphere.eye li:nth-child(8),
#sphere.eye li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Single */

#sphere.single ul:nth-child(n+2) {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Contact */

#sphere.contact ul {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sphere.contact ul:nth-child(1),
#sphere.contact ul:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#sphere.contact .rotator {
  -webkit-animation: spinHorizontal 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spinHorizontal 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spinHorizontal 2s linear infinite;
}

#sphere.contact ul:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: spinVerticalReverse 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spinVerticalReverse 5s linear infinite;
  animation: spinVerticalReverse 5s linear infinite;
}

#sphere.contact ul:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: spinVertical 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spinVertical 5s linear infinite;
  animation: spinVertical 5s linear infinite;
}

.contact .rotator {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms linear;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 500ms linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Half */

#sphere.half li {
  background: #000;
}

#sphere.half li:nth-child(n+12),
#sphere.half ul:nth-child(n+4) li:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}


/* Animations */


/*************************************************/

@-webkit-keyframes spinHorizontal {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinVertical {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinVerticalReverse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes borderRadius {
  from {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinHorizontal {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinVertical {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinVerticalReverse {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes borderRadius {
  from {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes spinHorizontal {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinVertical {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinVerticalReverse {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes borderRadius {
  from {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
}

.test p {
  text-align: center;
}

#controls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48px;
  top: 48px;
}

#controls fieldset {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0 0.5em;
}

#controls label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#controls div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}

#controls input {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Article: https://paulrhayes.com/2011-02/creating-a-sphere-with-3d-css/ -->
  <!-- Demo: https://paulrhayes.com/experiments/sphere/ -->
  <!-- Originally posted: 10th February 2011 -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>A sphere built with CSS 3D transforms &mdash; Paul Hayes</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Paul Hayes" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://paulrhayes.com/experiments/sphere/" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../experiment-styles.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/experiment.css" />
</head>

<body class="experiment">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="sphere" class="normal">
      <div class="rotator">
        <div class="container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Click and drag, use touch gestures or arrow keys.</p>
    <form id="controls" action="#">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="strong">Sphere styles</legend>
        <div>
          <input id="normal" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="normal" checked />
          <label for="normal">Normal</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="square" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="square" />
          <label for="square">Square</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="eye" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="eye" />
          <label for="eye">Eye</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="half" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="half" />
          <label for="half">Half</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="single" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="single" />
          <label for="single">Single</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="contact" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="contact" />
          <label for="contact">Contact</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="kaleidoscope" name="sphereType" type="radio" value="kaleidoscope" />
          <label for="kaleidoscope">Kaleidoscope</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/experiment.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если это ваш код добавьте комментарии в тело программы и хоть минимальный поясняющий текст.  Если вы скопировали код укажите ссылку на первоисточник. Ставлю плюс авансом, но жду выполнение моей просьбы.

Comment: благодарю за быструю реакцию и полезную ссылку

Answer (score 6):

Ответ ниже не является реальной 3D-формой. Это дает лишь небольшую иллюзию трехмерности, однако, в зависимости от вашего варианта использования, вы можете его подрегулировать:

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#222;}
div{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
    border-radius:50%;
    animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
    transform:rotate(-15deg);
    position:relative;
}
div:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    left:0;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    transform:rotate(15deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    
}
div:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;z-index:12;
    top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:50%;
box-shadow:inset -20px -20px 20px 2px #222, inset 20px 20px 20px 5px rgba(200,200,200,0.4);    
}
@keyframes spin{
    to{background-position:-300px 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Анимируя `background-position` div, и используя тени `box shadows`, вы можете «имитировать» затенение трехмерной фигуры.

Answer (score 6):

### Решение JS

Я использую `JavaScript` для построения сферы, которая состоит из множества элементов `div`. Чтобы поддерживать производительность браузера, элементы div делаются как можно меньше.

```js
var DIAMETER = 200;
var CELLS_PER_CIRCLE = 26;
var IMG_CELL = 'https://sites.google.com/site/zulnasibu/sphere/earth.png';
var NAME = 'sphere';
var WRAP = NAME + '-wrapper';
var _cssRules = '';
var _cellW;
var _cellAmount = 0;
var _imgW;
var _imgH;

function createFace(w, h, rx, ry, tz, ts, tsx, tsy, cname) {
 var face = document.createElement("div");
 var css;
 var cssText =
  'width: ' + w.toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'height: ' + h.toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'margin-left: ' + (-w / 2).toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'margin-top: ' + (-h / 2).toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'background: url("' + ts + '") ' + tsx.toFixed(2) + 'px ' + tsy.toFixed(2) + 'px;';
 css = 'transform: rotateY(' + ry.toFixed(2) + 'rad) rotateX(' + rx.toFixed(2) + 'rad) translateZ(' + tz.toFixed(2) + 'px);';
 cssText += addVendorPrefix(css);
 face.className = cname;
 face.style.cssText = cssText;
 return face;
}

function createModel() {
 var wrap = document.createElement("div");
 var model = document.createElement("div");
 wrap.className = WRAP;
 model.className = NAME;
 if (CELLS_PER_CIRCLE % 2 != 0) CELLS_PER_CIRCLE++;
 if (CELLS_PER_CIRCLE < 4) CELLS_PER_CIRCLE = 4;
 var baseAngle = Math.PI / CELLS_PER_CIRCLE;
 var cellAngle = 2 * baseAngle;
 _cellW = DIAMETER * Math.tan(baseAngle);
 _imgW = _cellW * CELLS_PER_CIRCLE;
 _imgH = CELLS_PER_CIRCLE / 2;
 if (CELLS_PER_CIRCLE % 4 == 0) _imgH++;
 _imgH *= _cellW;
 var xc = Math.ceil(CELLS_PER_CIRCLE / -4);
 var yc, rx, ry, tx, ty = -_imgH, tw, cang, cdia, cw;
 for (var x = xc; x <= -xc; x++) {
  rx = x * cellAngle;
  cw = _cellW;
  yc = CELLS_PER_CIRCLE;
  if (Math.abs(rx) == Math.PI / 2)
   yc = 1;
  else if (Math.abs(x) != 1) {
   cang = rx - Math.sign(x) * cellAngle / 2;
   cdia = DIAMETER * Math.cos(cang);
   cw = cdia * Math.tan(baseAngle);
  }
  _cellAmount += yc;
  tw = cw * yc;
  tx = (tw - _imgW) / 2;
  ty += _cellW;
  for (var y = 0; y < yc; y++) {
   ry = y * cellAngle;
   model.appendChild(createFace(cw + 1, _cellW + 1, rx, ry, DIAMETER / 2, IMG_CELL, tx, ty, 'cell' + x.toString() + y.toString()));
   tx -= cw;
  }
 }
 wrap.appendChild(model);
 var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.type = 'text/css';
 if (style.styleSheet)
  style.styleSheet.cssText = _cssRules;
 else
  style.innerHTML = _cssRules;
 document.head.appendChild(style);
 return wrap;
}

function addVendorPrefix(property) {
 return '-webkit-' + property +
   '-moz-' + property +
   '-o-' + property +
   property;
}

function showGeometry(elm) {
 if (elm.checked)
  document.querySelector('.sphere').classList.add('show-geometry');
 else
  document.querySelector('.sphere').classList.remove('show-geometry');
}

document.body.appendChild(createModel());
```

```css
.sphere-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-perspective: 1000px;
 -o-perspective: 1000px;
 perspective: 1000px;
}
.sphere {
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: center center -100px;
 -moz-transform-origin: center center -100px;
 -o-transform-origin: center center -100px;
 transform-origin: center center -100px;
 -webkit-animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
 -o-animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
 animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
}
.sphere div {
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 010.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
 010.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
 010.00% {-o-transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {-o-transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {-o-transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {-o-transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
@keyframes spin {
 010.00% {transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
input, input~ label {
 cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked~ label {
 color: #f77;
}
.show-geometry div {
 background: rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.5) !important;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
 -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
 -o-backface-visibility: visible;
 backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input id="show-geometry" type="checkbox" onchange="showGeometry(this);">
<label for="show-geometry">Show geometry</label>
```

[Источник ответа:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455508/7394871) @ZulNs

Comment: Сильный ответ. Но есть изьяны,- белые, неокрашенные сегменты. К сожалению эти дефекты есть и в первоисточнике. Просьба не повторять мой комментарий, что вот есть непрокраска, а подойти с деловой стороны, - попытаться найти ошибку и добавить новый ответ без дефектов окраски.   Это переводной топик, поэтому галочка и плюсы гарантированы автору качественного ответа.

Comment: добавьте комментарии в тело программы и минимальный поясняющий текст что за математические операции в JS ведутся?

Comment: @Demon __ ANT это переводной топик. Мог бы сам, сделал бы сам.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT обязательно подумаю над этим вопросом.