# Анимация для svg овала

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Есть такой макет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Овал вокруг надписи "Мужская коллекция" это как будто орбита планеты.
Сам сайт называется - *Planeta*.

Нужно придумать какую то анимацию с этим овалом. Любую, но хорошую. Сам пока не знаю как это сделать. Можете подсказать что то?

---

PS Это интернет магазин одежды. Mожно реализовать как наручные часы так, чтобы не было видно стрелок и вокруг этой орбиты вращалась планета. Скорее не SVG анимация, достаточно CSS анимации.

Answer (score 9):

### Анимация рисования овала

Используется изменение параметров `stroke-dasharray`

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:0,1859;
 stroke-dashoffset:-925;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:36px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="0s" values="0 1859;1859 0" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
<text x="225" y="350">МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Туда - обратно**

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:0,1859;
 stroke-dashoffset:-925;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:36px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
      dur="8s"
      begin="0s"
      values="
      0 1859;
      1859 0;
      1859 0;
      0 1859"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      fill="freeze" />
    </path>
<text x="225" y="350" font-size="36px" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="500" fill="#151515" >МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text> 
</svg>
</div>
```

**Анимация из одной точки**

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:0,1859;
 stroke-dashoffset:-925;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:36px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100vw" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate
   id="an_oval"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   dur="5s"
   begin="0s"
   values="
   0, 929.5 0, 929.5;0 0 1859,0;0, 929.5 0, 929.5"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  
  </path>  
    <text x="225" y="350"  >МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А я как всегда без svg)

Answer (score 8):

А может просто пусть что-нибудь летает типа планеты?

```css
section {
  height: 20em;
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: skew(-10deg, -15deg);
  margin: 2em auto;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skew(10deg, 15deg);
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

i::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 14.645%;
  top: 14.645%;
  margin: -1em 0 0 -1em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: antiquewhite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fix-circle 5s linear backwards infinite; 
}

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0)     }
  to   { transform: rotate(1turn) }
}

@keyframes fix-circle {
  from { transform: rotate(1turn) skew(10deg, 15deg) }
  to   { transform: rotate(0)     skew(10deg, 15deg) }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <i></i>
  <div>Мужская коллекция</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Qwerty Здорово. Тут много чего можно придумать. У меня была мысль шарик запустить, помнишь, как-то делал [анимацию планет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918238/28748) Решил, может автор что-то более конкретное скажет. А то ни кода и даже минимального нарпавления нет.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, там уже мой плюсик стоит. Но там орбиты круглые, а тут немного побольше шаманства :)

Answer (score 8):

Вот такие вот часики с претензией на дискретность хода:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(clock);

function clock(t, t2) {
  requestAnimationFrame(clock);
  relocate(sec, calc(6e4, 1e3, 0.8));
  relocate(min, calc(36e5, 6e4, 0.99));
}

function calc(k1, k2, k3){
  let t = Date.now() % k1;
  let x = t%k2 / k2;
  x = Math.max(0, x - k3);
  x /= 1 - k3;
  t = Math.floor(t/k2) + 3*x*x-2*x*x*x;
  return t*Math.PI/30;
}

function relocate(el, rad) {
  el.setAttribute('cx', Math.cos(rad)*50);
  el.setAttribute('cy', Math.sin(rad)*30);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-60,-60,120,120 height=90vh width=90vw>
  <g transform=rotate(-55) stroke=black stroke-width=0.5 >
    <ellipse rx=50 ry=30 fill=none />
    <circle id=min r=3 fill=white />
    <circle id=sec r=2 fill=black />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT привязка к реальным секундам и так тут есть

Comment: Опять скрипт)))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, зачем магазину одежды часы?)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT планета это назвпние сайта, по заявлению топикстартера

Answer (score 7):

Только как вариант возможной анимации для примера (без svg):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  overflow: visible;
  transition: color 0.7s;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 300px;
}

.box:after, 
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}


.box:before {
    animation-name: sAnim2, sAnim1;
    animation-duration: 5s, 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease, linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box:after {
    animation-name: sAnim2, sAnim0;
    animation-duration: 5s, 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease, linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}



@keyframes sAnim0 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 360deg);
  }
}


@keyframes sAnim1 {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 360deg);
  }
}


@keyframes sAnim2 {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%, 75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}



h2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem; 
}

h2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left:50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  margin-left: -40%;
  transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
}

h2 a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2:hover:after {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2><a href="#">Мужская коллекция</a></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Это выглядит круто

Answer (score 5):

### Анимация вращения сегментов окружности

Полная длина окружности равна `1859px` 
Используется `stroke-dasharray` для деления окружности на сегменты
`stroke-dashoffset` - для анимации вращения сегментов

**Два сегмента**

`stroke-dasharray:910.5,19;`
`stroke-dashoffset:1859`;

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:910.5,19;
 stroke-dashoffset:1859;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:36px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   dur="5s"
   begin="0s"
   values="1859;0"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
<text x="225" y="350">МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Три сегмента**

`stroke-dasharray:600.7,19;`

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:600.7,19;
 stroke-dashoffset:1859;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:36px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   dur="5s"
   begin="0s"
   values="1859;0"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
<text x="225" y="350">МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Четыре сегмента**

`stroke-dasharray:445.75,19;`

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:445.75,19;
 stroke-dashoffset:1859;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:36px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   dur="5s"
   begin="0s"
   values="1859;0"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
<text x="225" y="350">МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Update 26.12.2019

*Анимация вращения шарика с по орбите с одновременным вращением его вокруг своей оси*

**Чёрно-белый вариант**

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke:silver;
 stroke-width:4px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 
 }
 text {
 font-size:40px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:500;
 fill:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 fill:url(#gradCirc);
 }
 
.circ{
   fill:url(#gradCirc);
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter> 
<linearGradient id="gradCirc">
   <stop offset="5%" stop-color="white"></stop>
   <stop offset="40%" stop-color="silver"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#151515" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  </defs>  
  
  
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   dur="5s"
   begin="0s"
   values="1859;0"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
<text x="205" y="350">МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
   
 <circle class="circ"  cx="0" cy="0" r="25"  > 
  
    <animateMotion
   dur="10s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   additive="sum"
   rotate="auto-reverse">
          <mpath xlink:href="#oval"/>
    </animateMotion> 
<circle/> 
</svg>
</div>
```

**ЦВЕТНОЙ ВАРИАНТ ЛОГОТИПА**

Изменить цветовую гамму по своему вкусу довольно легко, - 
нужно поменять цвета у двух градиентов:

`fill:url(#gradText);` - градиент для текста и дуги

`fill:url(#gradCirc);` - градиент для шарика

В примере ниже сплошная линия заменена на пунктирную - `stroke-dasharray:25 8;`

Анимация вращения пунктирной линии **в разные стороны** достигается изменением
`stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения до нуля и обратно до максимального значения - `values="1859;0;0;1859"`

Повторяющиеся значения обеспечивают паузу вращения в крайних точках

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #oval {
 fill:none;
 stroke-width:4px;
 stroke-dasharray:25 8;
 stroke:url(#gradText);
 }
 text {
 font-size:40px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:500;
 stroke:silver;
 text-decoration: underline;
  fill:url(#gradText);
 }
 
.circ{
   fill:url(#gradCirc);
   
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 813 733" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="150%" width="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter> 
<linearGradient id="gradText">
   <stop offset="5%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#B34EE9" ></stop>
</linearGradient> 
  <linearGradient id="gradCirc">
   <stop offset="30%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" ></stop>
   <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#B34EE9" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>  
  </defs>  
  
  
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#F4F4F4" />
  <path id="oval"  d="m661.6 98.6c39.6 16.9 73.9 49.5 81.5 100.2 11.8 78-34.7 158.6-81.5 222.1-59.1 80.1-145 139.2-237.6 180.9-66.9 30.2-138.9 42.9-218.4 28.8-43.9-7.8-89.1-46.4-101.5-90.9C78.2 446.6 146.8 330.5 205 268.7 263.1 206.9 343.6 150.3 424 117.2 497.4 87 588.5 67.3 661.6 98.6Z">
    <animate id="an_oval"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   dur="16s"
   begin="0s"
   values="1859;0;0;1859"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
<text x="205" y="350">МУЖСКАЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ </text>
   
 <circle class="circ"  cx="0" cy="0" r="28"  > 
  
    <animateMotion
   dur="8s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   additive="sum"
   rotate="auto-reverse">
          <mpath xlink:href="#oval"/>
    </animateMotion> 
<circle/> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Более подробно, как это делается [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918237/28748)

Comment: Как у вас тут весело! Я даже скучаю)

Comment: @kizoso Приходи в Новогодний конкурс, там будет наверняка весело и поучаствуй конечно